# How to catch all $DISPLAY variables available per user

Tags: x11, environment-variables

How to get all `$DISPLAY` variables currently opened by a user?
In general it’s `:0` but if he open a new display, so another variable is set.

So how to catch all the available `$DISPLAY` variables available for a user?

Comment: Don't forget you can also open quite a few X client applications by specifying `-display` on the commandline. If you are only looking for local X servers (or forwardings, like from `ssh`), looking at the unix domain sockets for this might be simpler. And few people use X over the network today.

Comment: You're asking two completely different questions. 1. How to list all the DISPLAY endpoints _used_ by someone, 2. How to list all the display endpoints _available_ to someone. Which is it?

Comment: I think your question may be about how to find all the X11 sessions, not about variables. A start would be to look at `/tmp/.X11-unix/X*` but I am not sure how reliable it is and how to see if a user has access to the display. Anyway, you probably should edit the question to make clearer what you want to do.

Answer (score 6):

On GNU/Linux, to get values of the `DISPLAY` environment variables of all processes, you can do:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -zn 's/^DISPLAY=//p' /proc/*/environ |
  LC_ALL=C sort -zu |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

`sed` will need to run as `root` to get access to that information. If running as a regular user, you'll only get the information for processes running as that user.

A command that has been executed with `DISPLAY=some-display-spec` passed to it as an environment string means that it's been started in an environment where `some-display-spec` was the preferred X11 display target, for instance because it was started as part of a graphical X11 desktop session, or was started by `sshd` upon the request of a remote `ssh` client that had requested X11 forwarding.

But that doesn't necessarily mean that the process running that command will necessarily connect to that server to request its service (interact with the user), maybe because it interacts with the user some other way (like via the intermediary of a terminal emulator for terminal applications, or via audio...), or because it doesn't interact with the user at all. It could also connect to a X11 server but ignore that `$DISPLAY` variable because for instance it's been told to connect to a different one with some `-display`/`--display`/`-d`... option. With those options, you could also have processes connecting to X servers without having any `DISPLAY` variable in their environment.

---

To find out the available X11 displays served locally (by things like `Xorg`, `sshd`, `Xvnc`...), you could have a look at stream-type abstract or unix domain socket with `/tmp/.X11-unix/X<number>` as path:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -Po '^(\S+ ){3}0*10000 (?1){3}@?/tmp/.X11-unix/X\K\d+$' /proc/net/unix |
  LC_ALL=C sort -u
```

or on TCP ports from 6000 (for a `tcp/localhost:0` display) to some reasonable number above 6000 where you expect you may find a X server:

```
ss -nlt 'sport >= 6000 && sport < 6030'
```

In any case, whether a particular user will be able to connect to those servers and request display services from them will depend on how access control is configured for those which can be done in several ways and vary from one server to the next.

To query the authorisation settings for a given X11 display, you'd do:

```
DISPLAY=that-display xhost
```

But that's a bit of a catch 22 as you'd need to be authorized to access that display for that command to succeed.

Comment: For the moment, I’m just interested by displays locally opened. But the case of distant displays could interest any visitor coming in this tread.

Comment: @fauve, the scanning of `/proc/*/environ` would report the processes that connect to remote displays just the same. To scan for *available* remote displays, you'd need to scan (with things like `nmap`) all the computers within your reach, but in general, that's not the kind of thing you'd want to do. You generally rather want applications on remote hosts to connect to a display served by the computer you're sitting in front of.

Comment: A process run like `xterm -display :1` could be using a display without having it as an environment variable.  If it's a "normal" display with a window manager running locally on it, that process will almost certainly have an env var, but you can imagine something that acts like an X11 display but doesn't run other processes, just listens on a certain port.  (Oh, dirkt already commented about this under the question.)

Comment: @PeterCordes see edit

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering your, "*how to catch all the available `$DISPLAY` variables available for a user?*".

You don't always need to set `$DISPLAY` to have a client displayed elsewhere. For example,

```
xclock -display :2
```

Furthermore, it's potentially possible to have the application access a remote display,

```
xclock -display 192.168.1.55:0
```

When I worked on X display servers in the 1990s it was quite possible to run a client on a system that was several thousand miles/km away from the display server.

As a result, it's not possible to list all of the possible display servers available for a user *unless you have a specific set of criteria to apply*.